# JS chunks built with Expo web are too heavy

Tags: reactjs, expo, expo-web

I am building the web version of my mobile app and I am running into a huge size issue. When I run `expo build:web`, the bundled js chunk files, **2.xxxx.chunk.js** and **app.xxxx.chunk.js**, weight respectively 1.7mb and 1mb, which seems to be way too much.

For reference, I built the previous version of this website using ReactJS without expo, and the same two files were at about 466kb and 849kb. When opening that version in production, the Network tab shows that it takes less than 300kb for each of these chunks to be downloaded.

Is there anything I can do to reduce the size of these files?

This is on Expo sdk 39.

Comment: Yeah, I had to have an html, css, javascript only landing page for the main site and then make the Expo app be on an app.mydomain.com site. It was the only way I could figure out how to make the parent mydomain.com site faster. I added in cookies to automatically redirect to the app.mydomain.com if the user was logged in.